# Error: listen EADDRINUSE in websocket io and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have this server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8080,function(){
  console.log('server started');
});
console.log('tet');
```

And I add io.connect in services:

```
angular.module('installApp')
.factory('socket', function () {
// Service logic
// ...

var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://172.31.1.113:8080');
var socket = socketFactory({
  ioSocket: myIoSocket
});
// Public API here
return socket;
});
```

In my index.html:

```
<script src="http://172.31.1.113:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/socket.js"></script>
```

But when I run `node server.js`, I get the `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`. I think I did it right and I include all the scripts in my html. why i get this please help.

Comment: on which port you running the node server on?

Comment: I run it in port 8080

Comment: change port number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a different port number for the node server like 8888 or 80 so that the port does not conflict with the socket port.

Comment: webSockets are designed to be run on the same port as the web server.  In fact every webSocket connection starts with an http request.  In fact socket.io and node.js web servers co-exist just fine on the same port if properly installed.  This also drastically simplifies same-origin use from the client.